# yocto: REQUIRED_VERSION not working, if recipe does not exist

Tags: yocto, bitbake, recipe

I am using yocto with the current kirkstone LTS release(for a long time). I tried to use the version information for recipes.

See: https://docs.yoctoproject.org/4.0.6/ref-manual/variables.html?highlight=preferred_version#term-PV

So I have a recipe like this: 'my-recipe_1.0.0.bb'

Now I want to install that recipe in this version in my image. So I have another recipe like 'image.bb' that installs the recipe with something like: 'IMAGE_INSTALL += "my-recipe".

Now I want the build to fail, if that recipe version does not exist. I use REQUIRED_VERSION for this, see: https://docs.yoctoproject.org/4.0.6/ref-manual/variables.html?highlight=preferred_version#term-REQUIRED_VERSION

So I added in my image.bb a line like this: 'REQUIRED_VERSION_my-recipe="1.0.0"'

This works perfectly fine and I can switch this way between different versions of my recipe.

Now comes the question: If I require a version of my recipe that does not exist, the documentation says I will get an error and an immediate build error. But instead, my build takes an existing recipe but not the one I required.

This leads to an unacceptable situation where my build build something I do not expect.
Now I wonder, if somebody has an idea what is going wrong.

I tried to use the REQUIRED_VERSION for different existing recipes. -> That worked as expected.

I tried to use the REQUIRED_VERSION for a not existing recipe. -> That did not work as expected. I got no build error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the manual states that REQUIRED_VERSION "works in exactly the same manner as PREFERRED_VERSION" (except that it throws an error), maybe try using the forcevariable override:

```
REQUIRED_VERSION_my-recipe:forcevariable = "1.0.0"
```

Edit: Include this line in local.conf instead of the image.bb file for the expected behavior to take effect.

Comment: Good idea! I forgot to mention that I tried this one too. No change in behaviour.

Comment: Hmm.  What if you try including that line in local.conf instead of the image.bb file?

Comment: I will try that on monday and give feedback.

Answer (score 0):

> Hmm. What if you try including that line in local.conf instead of the
> image.bb file? –  thelummox Jan 13 at 16:11

Well, adding this to the local.conf raised the expected error. It even prints the available versions.

It is weird because local.conf is by definition not party of my layer but I can work with that.

Comment: Might I ask that you mark my answer as the accepted answer since it resolved your issue?

Comment: Well, I tried but I failed. So I quoted you. Now, I marked the upper thread as solved but I dont know how to mark your comment as solution.

Comment: Thanks.  I added the comment as an edit in the answer, so we're covered.

Comment: Inter-recipe configuration options (such as which one to give preference over others) must be put into a conf file. That's how Bitbake works. I'm unable to provide technical details, but I suffered from this as well.